# Derivative of a functional with a power of an absolute value

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f,g$ are continuous functions, and $h(t):=|f+tg|^p$, with $p>1$. Calculate $h'$

If $f+tg\neq0$, there's no problem, but if don't, i don't know how to approach this exercise. Looking I found that for complex functions
$$\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{t} = \frac{p}{2}|f|^{p-2}(\bar{f}g+f\bar{g})$$
but I can't prove it.

Any help.

Comment: This is just a composition of $x^p$, $|x|$ and $f, g, \times, +$.

Comment: But |x| is not differentiable on 0

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dt}|f+tg|^a$$

$$\frac{d}{dt} \big( \sqrt{(f+tg)^2}^a \big) $$

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\big(((f+tg)^2)^ \frac{a}{2}\big)$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}a \big((f+tg)^2\big)^{-1+ \frac{a}{2}} \big( \frac{d}{dt}(f+tg)^2\big)   $$

$$=\frac{1}{2}a \big((f+tg)^2\big)^{-1+ \frac{a}{2}} . 2(tg+f)\frac{d}{dt}(f+tg)$$

$$=a(f+tg) \big((f+tg)^2\big)^{-1+ \frac{a}{2}} \big(\frac{d}{dt}(f+g)\big) $$

$$=a(f+tg) \big((f+tg)^2\big)^{-1+ \frac{a}{2}} \big((0+g)\big) $$

$$=ag(f+tg) \big((f+tg)^2\big)^{-1+ \frac{a}{2}}$$